# Trying to make my deploy script work

Tags: git, shell, unix, heroku, gulp

I have several unix commands for git to push to heroku, but I have one problem, which I'm having trouble with. I have bower components which are in my `.gitignore` because they shouldn't be on the repo. So in the automated steps, it makes a new branch, deletes the `.gitignore` and adds the bower files for the Heroku push. Unfortunately at the end of the process I am left without my bower directory. How do I keep my bower directory?

#### gulpfile.coffee

```
gulp.task 'deploy', shell.task [
  'git checkout master'
  'git branch -D dist'
  'git stash'
  'git checkout -b dist'
  'rm .gitignore'
  'git add .gitignore --all'
  'gulp build',
  'git add public'
  'git commit -m "build for release"'
  'git push heroku dist:master --force'
  'git checkout master'
  'git branch -D dist'
  'git stash pop'
  'echo "Deployed."'
  'heroku open'
], ignoreErrors: true
```

#### .gitignore

```
public/components/bower
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you checkout master, you can do the following before deleting the `dist` branch:

```
git checkout dist -- public/components/bower
git reset
```

Comment: Good call. I knew about checkout, but the solution was evading me! :) #brainfreeze